# How to prove continuity in terms of convergent sequences directly?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $E,E'$ be metric spaces. Then a function $f:E\to E'$ is continuous
>   at $p_0 \in E$ if and only if, for every sequence of points $p_1, p_2,
>  p_3,...$ in $E$ such that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} p_n=p_0$$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n)=f(p_0).$$

I know how to prove $f$ is continuous at $p_0$ implies for every sequence of points $p_1, p_2,p_3,...$ in $E$ such that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} p_n=p_0$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n)=f(p_0).$

But I don't know how to prove the other direction. It is proved by contradiction in the textbook. I tried to prove it directly by using this definition:

> $E,E'$ are metric spaces. $f:E\to E'$ is continuous at $p_0$ if and
>   only if, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. if $p\in
>  E$ and $d(p,p_0)< \delta$, then $d'(f(p),f(p_0))<\epsilon$.

But I had trouble setting my $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Any help?

Comment: A *constructive* proof is impossible.  You have to argue by contradiction since you can't use any inequalities concerning $\epsilon-N$ to obtain  $\delta$.

Comment: Before doing contradiction, you could try proving the contrapositive. If $f$ is not continuous at $p$ then there exists a sequence $\{p_n\}$ that converges to $p$ and $\{f(p_n)\}$ does not converge to $f(p)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that for all sequences $\left\{p_n\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$ tending to $p_0$, the sequence $\left\{f(p_n)\right\}_{n=0}^\infty$ tends to $f(p_0)$. By way of contradiction, assume that $f$ is discontinuous at $p_0$.

Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $p\in E$ such that $d(p, p_0) < \delta$ but $d^\prime(f(p), f(p_0)) \geq \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon$ be as such and for each $\delta_n = 1/n$, find $p_n \in E$ such that $d(p_n, p_0) < \delta_n = 1/n$ but $d^\prime(f(p_n), f(p_0)) \geq \epsilon$. Then, by definition of the limit, $p_n \to p_0$ but $f(p_n) \not\to f(p_0)$.

Comment: Your proof is the same as the proof in my text. Couldn't we prove it directly?

Comment: @User0.618 A direct proof is impossible. The condition provides information on the convergence, but does not give you enough information about the rates.