# Prove that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $x_n\to x$ implies that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ when $X$ is sequential

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

**Definition**

A topological space $X$ is said sequential when a subet $Y$ is not closed if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $Y$ convergint to a point $x_0$ of $X\setminus Y$.

So as exercise in the text *Elementos de Topología General* by Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa and Fidel Casarrubias Segura is asked to prove the following result.

> **Theorem 3.D.8.b**
>
> A function $f$ from a sequential space $X$ to a space $Y$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $x_0$ has immage $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $f(x_0)$.

So unfortunately I was not able to prove the previous theorem and moreover I did no find it in any text but in the text *General Topology* by Ryszard Engelking I found the following proposition

[image]

which is surely similar to the theorem $3$.D.$8$.b but it is different. Perhaps can the theorem $3$.D.$8$.b be proved by the proposition 1.6.15? Moreover if this was true I point out that I did not understand the proof of $1.6.15$ because it is not clear how make the sequence in $f^{-1}[B]$ and then is not clear why $f^{-1}[B]$ is closed so that in this case I ask to explain these thigs. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Hey! See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4380300/861687.

Comment: @user264745 I see: however it seems that it does not help. Perhaps are you able to prove that a sequential space is metrizable?

Comment: @user264745 I do not think.

Comment: Rephrasing theorem 3.D.8.b: suppose $f$ be a function from a sequential space $X$ to a space $Y$. Show $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $x_0$ has immage $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $f(x_0)$. $\Rightarrow$ holds for general topological space. In this implication we don’t need sequential space condition. $\Leftarrow$ I’m also trying. But I can’t prove it. Can you show if $x\in \overline{A}$, then $\exists$ sequence in $A$ such that that sequence converge to $x$.

Comment: @user264745 I already knew the first implication; the problem is exactly the second implication as you observed by your self. Anyway as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440492/prove-or-disprove-that-x-0-in-operatornamecl-y-iff-there-exists-a-sequence?noredirect=1&lq=1) you can see I am not sure that for any point of $\ovelrine A$ there exists a sequence in $A$ converging there.

Comment: Can you offer bounty for this post?

Comment: @user264745 I do not know: Oliver Díaz [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440492/prove-or-disprove-that-x-0-in-operatornamecl-y-iff-there-exists-a-sequence/4440950?noredirect=1#comment9299319_4440950) effectively proved the theorem: the only one mistery if it is hols pointwise too but I think that this is genrally false because many text (e.g. Engelking) proves it only globally. Perhaps do you know if it holds pointwise too?

Comment: My knowledge of topology is not wide, you can see my posts(I’m beginner, essentially). Henno Brandsma is not active now. I will check/read [Oliver Diaz answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4440950/861687). I can’t wait see how one would prove this problem.

Comment: Oliver Diaz didn’t solve for continuity at a single point. I don’t think I have any chance.

Comment: @user264745 I know that Oliver Diaz did not prove pointwise continuity and the same thing the professor Brandsma did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343261/sequentially-continuous-implies-continuous) so surely pointwise continuity is not trivial provided obviously it does not fails.